# CoffeeScript: Callback.call Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'm adding a loading spinner to a page calling an API on localhost. Previously, the code looked like:

```
getDocumentContents: (id, callback) ->

  $.ajax(
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/doc/' + id
    type: 'GET'
      contentType: 'application/json'   
      success: callback
  )
```

It uses the jQuery $.ajax function and it works, calling the callback but not indicating to the user that anything is happening.

Adding code for the spinner class adding/removing and manually calling the callback does not work. The spinner appears and disappears as expected, but the callback never triggers and no JS errors show up in my console:

```
getDocumentContents: (id, callback) ->

  $.ajax(
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/doc/' + id
    type: 'GET'
      contentType: 'application/json'
      beforeSend: ->
        $('#sidePanelBody i.article-spinner').addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw')
     success: ->
        $('#sidePanelBody i.article-spinner').removeClass('fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw')
        callback.call
  )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) Is that your real indentation? (2) `callback.call` is simply a function reference, `callback.call()` OTOH is a function invocation with no arguments; function-calling parentheses are needed in CoffeeScript when there are no arguments.

Comment: Yes, this was part of the problem, I discovered. Looks like I also left out a parameter name that normally gets quietly passed in on the success call. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Mu pointed out, the function call needed () rather than .call. I had assumed the latter syntax from the assumption I made that CoffeeScript didn't want parens. I was also missing the "data" parameter which was previously being passed in automatically and apparently now needed to be declared explicitly in both the function closure as well as the callback call. This code works:

```
success: (data) ->
  $('#sidePanelBody i.article-spinner').removeClass('fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw')
  callback(data)
```